# Magento 2 custom config form in admin panel is empty

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, adminform

I followed this tutorial https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-an-admin-form-look-like-a-configuration-page-magento-2-configuration-p3/#3createa_layout_file_with_url_path.

It shows how to create a setup form for custom modules.
However for some reasons it's showing me everything empty, except for the name of the module and Store View.

[image]

This is my system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="sift" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Sift</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="section" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Hello World</label>
            <tab>Sift</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::menu_item</resource>
            <group id="sift" >
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="debug_enable" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enable Debug</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>

                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

This is my acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_Module::menu">
                    <resource id="Vendor_Module::menu_item" title="Configuration" sortOrder="80" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

and finally config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <section>
            <sift>
        <debug_enable>1</debug_enable>
            </sift>
        </section>
    </default>
</config>
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: I think it's your group id and tab id name issue. Can you change that name and check please.

Comment: Hello, I made it worked. I practically redo the whole thing because it was not working, also I could not make work with the controller that I was using, so I changed the action of my menu in menu.xml to adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/(name of the section)